# Read User input in C language

Tags: c

How do i prompt user to enter a country name such as `Malaysia` to replace the variable `country1` to `Malaysia` ?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
    writeRecipe (int fd)
   {
     readData ();
     char country1[LINE_MAX] = "China";
     static char* line1 = "Starting Country Search Client ...\n\n\n";
     static char* line2 = "**********************************************";
     static char* line3 = "Welcome to the Country Info Directory Service!";
     static char* line4 = "**********************************************\n\n";

     write (fd, line1, strlen (line1) + 1); /* Write first line */
     write (fd, line2, strlen (line2) + 1); /* Write second line */
     write (fd, line3, strlen (line3) + 1); /* Write third line */
     write (fd, line4, strlen (line4) + 1); /* Write fourth line */


     puts("Please enter country > ");
     fgets(country1, sizeof country1,stdin);
     printf ("\n%s Capital       : %s\n", country1, getCapital (country1));
     printf ("%s Currency Code : %s\n", country1, getCurrencyCode (country1));
   }
```

Comment: Throw away `scanf()`. Throw it away as far as you can, at least do so while you are a beginner. `fgets()` is your friend.

Comment: Also, this has absolutely nothing to do with either Linux or Netbeans.

Comment: And you have a typo in your second printf line

Answer (score 3):

> How do i prompt user to enter a country name such as Malaysia

This is how:

```
puts("Please enter a country name:");
```

Now, if you want to **actually** read in user input:

```
char buf[LINE_MAX] = "China";
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
```

Don't do anything else. Seriously. This is safe, simple and nice.

Comment: i need to use this line char* Country1 instead of char Country

Comment: @WenjieChia You "need" to? Why? I doubt.

Comment: Would I have to do `#define my_max 100` for the example I gave and then use that for the array and in fgets?

Comment: @DummyCode No, you better use the C standard library macro `LINE_MAX` - the same thing I used. Even better, test for its availability using the `#ifdef` preprocessor directive, and use the alternatives (for example, `_POSIX_LINE_MAX` as needed.

Comment: @H2CO3 Ah... Okay. Thanks. Sorry for the crappy answer.

Comment: +1, OP, after `fgets` you can remove trailing newline using: `char *pos; if ((pos=strchr(buf, '\n')) != NULL) *pos = '\0';`

Comment: @WenjieChia, in your edit you don't remove the trailing newline, in consequence, you are printing and extra `'\n'`